# sublime text 4: go to function definition not working when folder structure is different

Tags: sublimetext4

I am using sublime text 4 (4113 build)

I have a python project

some basic folder structure of django project

```
project_folder
-- venv (python virtual env)
-- src
----- test
---------models.py
```

Now in my models.py i have

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
```

Now I can go to AbstractBaseUser by pressing F12

whereas with this folder structure

```
project_folder
---venv (python virtual env)
---test
-----models.py
```

the go to definition does not work.

When the venv folder lies in beside the django files the go to definition does not work.

Comment: Do you have all the folders in `project_folder` added to your `.sublime-project`?

Comment: yes. I have all the folders.